# Why is this String undefined in my method?

Tags: java, undefined-function

Here is my method

```
public String isOpen() {
    if (fridge.isOpen()) {
        return String("The refrigerator is open.");
    }
}
```

and I get this error on the return line.

`The method String(String) is undefined for the type Kitchen`

I don't understand why String is undefined. Isn't it a universal part of java that doesn't care if you are inside a class called Kitchen?

Comment: There is a String class in Java that's part of the core language, but that doesn't mean that there is automatically a method called "String" that exists on every class.  If you want to return a string, then just `return "some string";`.

Comment: Did you mean to write `return new String(...)`? Voting to close as typo. Also, you're going to get another compilation error because one of your execution paths doesn't return a value.

Comment: try this : return new String("The refrigerator is open.");

Comment: @Vish: never recommend that as that throws out all benefit of the String pool. Just do `return "the refrig is open";` is adequate, sufficient, and better than using `new String(...)`.

Comment: It wasn't a typo, I don't know what it would do if I used ```return new String(...);```
Anyways I figured out the problem. I had tried doing the ```return "some string";``` way of doing it but like Sotirios Delimanolis said, one of the execution paths didn't return so if the fridge was closed it didn't return a string.
Anyways now I have an answer, is there a way to mark both of your answers as answers since they were both a vital piece?

Comment: You can upcast the comment or answer thats enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String is not a method, is a class. So, if you want to return a String you have to use the constructor of the class String, or use the simpler way, just return text between "".

So, instead of

```
return String("The refrigerator is open.");
```

do

```
return "The refrigerator is open.";
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return a new string, right? When calling a constructor, you need to use the keyword "new" (works out nicely, right?).

```
return new String("The refrigerator is open.");
```

Even though what you are going for is technically correct, Java provides some syntactic sugar (syntax that violates the conventions of the language to make it nicer for people) for this kind of thing, so you can just write:

```
return "The refrigerator is open.";
```